# How to find all offset postions of term using Apache Lucene

Tags: apache, indexing, lucene, offset, frequency

I am trying to find all **offset** postions of given term. For instance I have input: "dog cat orange dog green dog" And i would like to find **offsets** for term: "dog". The **result** would be: 0,15,25.

```
 Terms terms =  indexReader.getTermVector(0,"text");
 TermsEnum iterator  = terms.iterator();
 BytesRef byteRef = null;

 while((byteRef = iterator.next()) != null) 
     String term = byteRef.utf8ToString(); //here I find term name

 /* Here I only know about term frequency and  first offset(0) for given term not all of them */
```

Lets say I have a **term,** that occured 3 times while indexing like above. I would like to get array containing all offsets for term occurences.

Now i am getting only one offset for each **term**. How i can gather more information. I would be grateful for any help.

**EDIT:**

```
    FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();

    fieldType.setTokenized(true);
    fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
    fieldType.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
    fieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
```

Comment: Did you set term vector positions `true` in indexing phase?

Comment: hi, i updated my post and add code part for creating FieldType. Do u know how to get whole TermVectorOffset for conrete term then?

Comment: can u help please?